# RegistryError: Cant't find 'spacy.Tokenizer.v1' in registry spacy -> tokenizers. Available names: none

Tags: python, anaconda, spyder, tokenize

I am trying to:

- Tokenize CV from a pdf

This is what I have done:

```
pages = []
nlp = spacy.load("fr_core_news_sm")
test = "C:\\Users\\admin\\OneDrive\\Bureau\\Stage\\file.pdf"
def return_token(p):
    read_pdf = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(test)
    number_of_pages = read_pdf.getNumPages()
    for page_number in range(number_of_pages):  
        page = read_pdf.getPage(page_number) 
        p = page.extractText().replace('\n','')
        pages.append(page)`enter code here`
    doc = nlp(p)
    return [X.text for X in doc]
    return_token(p)
```

Error:

```
RegistryError: Cant't find 'spacy.Tokenizer.v1' in registry spacy -> tokenizers. Available names: none
```

Comment: Did you test whether spacy was working with simple text ? `nlp('Un exemple')` you can also execute `$python -m spacy validate` to check whether there is a problem with spacy.

Answer (score 1):

This error came to me as well and it was resolved via restarting the kernel.